# How to remove the rightmost button from MediaPlayer bar

Tags: media-player, uwp-xaml

I have a video player in my UWP app, and I want to get rid of some buttons on the seek bar bar.
This is the layout:

```
    <MediaPlayerElement x:Name="VideoElement"
                        AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                        AutoPlay="True">
        <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
            <MediaTransportControls IsZoomButtonVisible="False" IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False" />
        </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement>
```

[image]

I successfully removed "fullscreen" and "zoom" buttons, but I do not know how to remove this "playback on device" button. Does anyone know what field in `MediaTransportControls` controls it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to remove the rightmost button from MediaPlayer bar

The rightmost button is `CastButton` you could find it in `MediaTransportControls` style. You could set the property `Opacity="0" IsEnabled="False"` to hide it.

```
<AppBarButton x:Name='CastButton' Opacity="0" IsEnabled="False"
    Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
    MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='11'>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEC15;" />
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```